# Domain name issues [1&1]

Tags: domains, dns

I'm trying to make my domain name point to my web-server.

I own a domain through 1&1, and I have a linux computer I have set up to run as my web-server. I'm a student at college, and my college actually is its own ISP. While my IP is not technically static, it only changes maybe once a month, and I also have a sub-domain off the college's website that points to that computer which **is** static.

First, I tried to forward my domain to the subdomain that points to my computer, but 1&1 won't let me do that (I don't know why, but it tells me invalid url). So then, using 1&1 name-servers, I tried to make the A-record point to my server. That still doesn't work.

So how can I get my domain to point to my web-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the A record which points to the IP address of your computer. This process takes upto 48 hours, its not instant. You should then check to see if the record exists, by doing a domain resolve and see where it points too...

Also you should make sure you can access the PC using just the IP as colleges often have firewalls.